# How do I uncompress .bz file contents and convert it to plain enlish

Tags: java, amazon-s3, compression, inputstream, bzip

I have .bz file contents in `s3 bucket`.

Using S3Object , I'm able to read the file :

```
S3Object object = s3.getObject(bucket, path);
S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = object.getObjectContent();
```

Now I want to uncompress this content.

Tried, converting using the below code, but it is still giving me machine readable text but not english text.

```
    String text = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        .lines()
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

how do I get the uncompressed text here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a library.

For example [Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/).

```java
S3Object object = s3.getObject(bucket, path);
S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = object.getObjectContent();

BZip2CompressorInputStream bzInputStream = new BZip2CompressorInputStream(inputStream);

// Then just write to a string.
// This is Java 9+.

String plaintext = new String(bzInputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```